# Prevent xss in html onclick, onmouseout, ... for SPA

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, xss

I'm using `AngularJS` and `ASP.Net Web API 2` for my customer survey system.

My web use a `wysiwyg` component to help user inputs his/her data.
This is the html generated by my `wysiwyg` I'm using:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Click here</strong></span><strong> to start using the </strong><strong><em>HTML editor online</em></strong></h2>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Please</span><span style="font-weight: 400;"> try out the WYSIWYG HTML editor features found in the kitchen sink above to edit and format your text and images</span></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">You&rsquo;ll see the content created in the WYSIWYG-HTML editor in source code format on the right.</span><br /><br /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img onclick="alert('Hello world')" onmouseout="alert('Mouse out')" src="https://icon2.kisspng.com/20180416/ucw/kisspng-tanki-online-video-gaming-clan-world-of-tanks-avat-joker-5ad4b1028d0565.2188790515238883865776.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="260" /></p>
```

This is what I'm doing on API for encoding the html code above.

```
/// Encode submited html content
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("encode")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Encode([FromBody] EncodeViewModel httpContent)
        {
            if (httpContent == null)
            {
                httpContent = new EncodeViewModel();
                Validate(httpContent);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var encodedHtmlContent= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(httpContent.HtmlContent);

            // Save content to database here.
            return Ok(encodedHtmlContent);
        }
```

When my front-end client load the encoded html and display to website page.
I want that there will be no message **Hello world** or **Mouse out** displayed when I click on the image.

That means, I only allow text, images, videos to be displayed, but don't allow inline code in the content.

Are there any solutions for this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that some piece of `html` is safe is *hard*! There are libraries to do html XSS filtering, but they are large and its still dangerous. Thats why there are things like [mobiledoc](https://github.com/bustle/mobiledoc-kit). In general I would recommend you to not use HTML as your WYSIWYG *output*, then you dont have to escape it. Rather use something else and generate the HTML from it. Then you can be sure you dont generate dangerous HTML. Still be careful if you do simple string concatenations.

This is why we have things like BB-Code or wiki markup or mobiledoc.

Comment: I've found a topic about **CSP** (Content-security policy). What do you think if I use CSP to protect untrusted javascript code ?

Comment: Don't do this! CSP is meant as *additional* security layer. You have no guarantee that a browser supports it. Either do the hard HTML escaping or don't use HTML for it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Especially IE11, it only support CSP partially. What if I sanitize user content submitted by `wysiwyg` control, remove all dangerous attribute (using  `HttpUltility` library). Will it have any pitfalls ?

Comment: as i said, its *hard* to sanitize html! its not only about attributes. think about dangerous tags. also remember that its not XML, its SGML! And even a incomplete tag might be fixed by the browser. Also what if new events come into browsers? You need to whitelist! But even then its not safe. Even CSS can be dangerous. Think about an transparent `<a>` tag thats spans the entire page and has an `javascript:` `href`. Either use a library, but know that even a good library will probably not be 100% safe, because its so hard! Doing it yourself is a huge amout of work or insecure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm thinking about BBCode as you mentioned. I have tried the solutions I told you above, not satisfied with what they have done.

Comment: Mobiledoc definitely can do what you want. It's just some customization